# Simple Login Button Facebook iOS SDK v.4.0.1 does not work

Tags: ios, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I must integrate the facebook login function in my iOS app. I downloaded the latest version of the Facebook SDK, the 4.0.1. I implemented the simple button with the class FBSDKLoginButton. When I click the login button the simulator goes to Safari where I insert the credentials and the app is authorized.
When it returns in the app view the button does not switch to logout button and no token.

The code goes in the branch result.isCancelled of the next method

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
              error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        // Process error
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        // Navigate to other view
    }
}
```

In the appdelegate.m i put the method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: First I would go back through: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#login-button to see what you may have missed.

Comment: It may be helpful to see more of the code from your view controller that contains FBSDKLoginButton.

Comment: I follow the instructions on the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#login-button but I think that in tutorial something missing

Comment: What happens on actual device?

Comment: I did not install on device yet

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the login button problem configurin the app in facebook developers dashboard. The problem now is that if i set

```
self.loginButton.delegate = self;
```

when I click on LogOut button the app crashes with objc_release.

Suggestions?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Couldn't find it on the FB docs and it was definitely my problem. Such an obvious one too!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, you need this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[FBSDKLoginButton class];
...
return YES;
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#login-button

Comment: i have this code in my app delegate. Without it the button will be not displayed...